# No closing tags while building xml file with MarkupBuilder

Tags: xml, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use Groovy in my Jenkins-Pipeline-Job to build a Statuslist of my Jenkins Slaves and the installed nodes. Therefore I have some lists which should be displayed in xml. While testing with IntelliJ i wrote the following code.

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def listNodeNames = []
listNodeNames << 'SLAVE1_NODE_1'
listNodeNames << 'SLAVE1_NODE_2'
listNodeNames << 'SLAVE2_NODE_1'
listNodeNames << 'SLAVE2_NODE_2'


def listComputerNames = []
listComputerNames << 'SLAVE1'
listComputerNames << 'SLAVE2'

def stringWriter = new StringWriter()
def xmlBuilder = new MarkupBuilder(stringWriter)

xmlBuilder.computers {
    for (i = 0; i < listComputerNames.size(); i++){

        xmlBuilder.computer {
            xmlBuilder.computerName("${listComputerNames[i]}")
            xmlBuilder.computerStatus("online")

            for (j = 0; j < listNodeNames.size(); j++){
                if (listNodeNames[j].contains(listComputerNames[i])){
                    xmlBuilder.slave {
                        xmlBuilder.slaveName("${listNodeNames[j]}")
                        xmlBuilder.slaveStatus('test')
                        xmlBuilder.slaveReason('test')
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

def xml = stringWriter.toString()
println xml
```

As long as i run the code in IntelliJ, everything works fine and i get a valid xml file:

```
  <computers>
      <computer>
        <computerName>SLAVE1</computerName>
        <computerStatus>online</computerStatus>
        <slave>
          <slaveName>SLAVE1_NODE1</slaveName>
          <slaveStatus>test</slaveStatus>
          <slaveReason>test</slaveReason>
        </slave>
        <slave>
          <slaveName>SLAVE1_NODE2</slaveName>
          <slaveStatus>test</slaveStatus>
          <slaveReason>test</slaveReason>
        </slave>
      </computer>
      <computer>
        <computerName>SLAVE2</computerName>
        <computerStatus>online</computerStatus>
        <slave>
          <slaveName>SLAVE2_NODE1</slaveName>
          <slaveStatus>test</slaveStatus>
          <slaveReason>test</slaveReason>
        </slave>
        <slave>
          <slaveName>SLAVE2_NODE2</slaveName>
          <slaveStatus>test</slaveStatus>
          <slaveReason>test</slaveReason>
        </slave>
      </computer>
    </computers>
```

But if i execute the same script on my Jenkins instance most closing tags are missing:

```
<computers>
  <computer>
    <computerName>SLAVE1</computerName>
    <computerStatus>online</computerStatus>
    <slave>
      <slaveName>SLAVE1_NODE1</slaveName>
      <slaveStatus>test</slaveStatus>
      <slaveReason>test</slaveReason>
      <slave>
        <slaveName>SLAVE1_NODE2</slaveName>
        <slaveStatus>test</slaveStatus>
        <slaveReason>test</slaveReason>
        <computer>
          <computerName>SLAVE2</computerName>
          <computerStatus>online</computerStatus>
          <slave>
            <slaveName>SLAVE2_NODE1</slaveName>
            <slaveStatus>test</slaveStatus>
            <slaveReason>test</slaveReason>
            <slave>
              <slaveName>SLAVE2_NODE2</slaveName>
              <slaveStatus>test</slaveStatus>
              <slaveReason>test</slaveReason>
```

Am i doing something wrong or are there specific steps to do while creating xml files via jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I don't really understand why but the `MarkupBuilder`hast du be capsuled inside a `@nonCPS`marked method. If I call this method jenkins performs as expected.

```
@nonCPS
def buildXml(list1, list2){
    //generate xml from lists
}

buildXml(list1, list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is really strange.

You may try below and see if that helps.

```
def listNodeNames = ['SLAVE1_NODE_1', 'SLAVE1_NODE_2', 'SLAVE2_NODE_1', 'SLAVE2_NODE_2']

def listComputerNames = ['SLAVE1', 'SLAVE2']

def xml = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    computers {
      listComputerNames.collect { cn ->
          computer {
             computerName(cn)
             computerStatus('online')
             listNodeNames.collect { slv ->
                if (slv.startsWith(cn)){
                   slave {
                     slaveName(slv)
                     slaveStatus('test')
                     slaveReason('test')
                   }
                }
             }
          }
      }
    }
}

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

Comment: With your code I get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'computers' found among steps [acceptGitLabMR, addGitLabMRComment, archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun [,,,]` error. In my version I was able to resolve this whilst adding `xmlBuilder.` in front of each node declaration. (building this with IntelliJ and via groovy.bat command works fine)

Comment: By the way, you can try wrapping each node name between the single quote `'` in the above solution and see if that helps.

Comment: Isnt the demo the same code than the code in your answer? Even with the `'`I get the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'computers' ` message. This is really weird,,,

Comment: Same. Just to get idea that the code is working as desired in plain groovy. Really no voice in jenkins.

Comment: I think this has to be a jenkins bug. if I delete everything berween  `xmlBuilder.computer { }` the output gives me : `[Pipeline] echo
<computers
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline` even if I add more entries, the last opening tag is always "broken"

Comment: Very strange. Isn't it possible to run the goovy to update the xml using command-line and use that xml later?

Comment: It's not a Jenkins bug as such. The issue is that Jenkins pipeline library syntax isn't exactly standard groovy, but a DSL based on groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Use function nodeCompleted('','computers') which will fix this issue

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def listNodeNames = []
listNodeNames << 'SLAVE1_NODE_1'
listNodeNames << 'SLAVE1_NODE_2'
listNodeNames << 'SLAVE2_NODE_1'
listNodeNames << 'SLAVE2_NODE_2'


def listComputerNames = []
listComputerNames << 'SLAVE1'
listComputerNames << 'SLAVE2'

def stringWriter = new StringWriter()
def xmlBuilder = new MarkupBuilder(stringWriter)

xmlBuilder.computers {
    for (i = 0; i < listComputerNames.size(); i++){

        xmlBuilder.computer {
            xmlBuilder.computerName("${listComputerNames[i]}")
            xmlBuilder.computerStatus("online")

            for (j = 0; j < listNodeNames.size(); j++){
                if (listNodeNames[j].contains(listComputerNames[i])){
                    xmlBuilder.slave {
                        xmlBuilder.slaveName("${listNodeNames[j]}")
                        xmlBuilder.slaveStatus('test')
                        xmlBuilder.slaveReason('test')
                    }
                    nodeCompleted('computers','slave')
                }
            }
        }
        nodeCompleted('','computers')

    }
}

def xml = stringWriter.toString()
println xml
```